# Style onCreateContextMenu

Tags: android, listview

Can I change the style of the box that appears when I long pressed on a Listview. As the image[image] where is written "delete" Could i change the background color, text size, etc.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604562/override-context-menu-colors-in-android). If it's possible, the key will be in overriding the default styles.