# Aligning context menu for android

Tags: android, android-layout, contextmenu

Context Menu always appear at the center of the screen. Is it possible to change the background of context menu and to position it were we want.

Comment: try this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604562/override-context-menu-colors-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can easily modify context menu (without any hacks) since its system defined. However, you may use `Dialog` to act as context menu and modify it as you want

Comment: How to use Dialog as Context Menu. Can you give one sample link.