# How to give background into context menu items

Tags: android, menu

In one of my Android projects, I am creating a context menu from a menu folder inside res. It is as below.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@+id/help"
    android:title="Help" />
  <item android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:title="Keyboard" />
  <item android:id="@+id/exit"
    android:title="Exit" />
</menu>
```

But I want an image to the background of every item. How can I do this?

Comment: It is a repeat question, and you can find it here: [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604562/override-context-menu-colors-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@+id/help"
    android:title="Help" 
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_1/>
  <item android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:title="Keyboard"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_2" />
  <item android:id="@+id/exit"
    android:title="Exit" 
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_3/>
</menu>
```

Comment: read my question,i need background image not icon.i know how to give icon.

Comment: There is no other way. You must set big images.

Answer (score -1):

Use [styles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) in your app. Then you can change a default style of Widget.ListView. Note this also  changed a style of dialogs with ListView. More details see in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604562/override-context-menu-colors-in-android).