# Android: Theme ContextMenu item selection

Tags: android, themes, contextmenu, selector

How can I theme the list seletor in a ContextMenu? For ListViews I used the way described here:

http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/understanding-android-themes-and-styles/

So I assigned the created style to my theme like this:

```
<style name="Theme...." parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/ListView</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43159882/2522264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Override context menu colors in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604562/override-context-menu-colors-in-android) and see if it helps.  It says you can't override the standard context menu selector but goes on to give code for context on long-press.

To theme any list item I assign a background on the lists xml, such as android:background="@layout/customshape, custon shape being something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle"> 
<gradient android:startColor="@color/white" 
      android:endColor="@color/light_grey_background" 
      android:angle="270"/> 
<corners 
android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" 
android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
android:topLeftRadius="7dp" 
android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```

Which I call from the list item .xml with something like:

```
 <LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:paddingTop="2dip"
 android:paddingBottom="2dip"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 >

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@layout/customrecipeshape"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <ImageView 
     android:id="@+id/listicon" 
     android:layout_width="34px" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:src="@drawable/icon_red" 
 />
 <TextView android:id="@+id/thing1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textColor="@color/black"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>    


 <TextView android:id="@+id/thing2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20px" 
        android:textColor="@color/grey21"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
 <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/thing3"

     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textColor="@color/grey21"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
     />




  </LinearLayout>
```

And as stated here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/GY9DFX2H-Bc

You can't override the custom context menu, but you can make your own using a listview and an alert dialog.