# ContextMenu in Material Design

Tags: android, material-design

I want to make my app in Material Design, but one thing I noticed was that the ContextMenus are themed in Holo, as seen here: [image: here].

Is there a way to make the context menu Material Themed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this post helps:

[Styling the popup menu in Android 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699482/styling-the-popup-menu-in-android-5-0)

They try to do exactly the opposite there. Note that using the ActionBar and using the right application/activity theme should do the trick.

This however is for the ActionBar context menu. I think the longpress ListView context menu is being phased out. It might be possible to make a custom theme for it though:

[Android: Theme ContextMenu item selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981530/android-theme-contextmenu-item-selection)