# Android - material design - how to set the background color for a context menu

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop

For a listview I have a context menu (on items). How can I set (via a style) the background color of the context menu?

From examples I used the following base theme:

```
<style name="Base.Theme.Xyz" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I am thankful for the previous answer, I found the perfect and very simple solution.

In my project I used this parent:

```
<style name="Base.Theme.Deholtmans" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

I got very dark context menu's, etc. Before AppCompat I used the Light version of themes.

The solution is using the right pre-defined parent:

```
<style name="Base.Theme.Deholtmans" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

So, the light version. Easy does it!

Answer (score 3):

just follow these steps:

> If by context menu you mean the menu from the long press, then I have
> done this with the following code.  My menu has my theme's background,
> and a green highlight.
>
> context menu layout:
>
> ```
> <menu
>   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
> <item android:id="@+id/resetConfirm" android:title="@string/actual_reset"></item>
> </menu>
> ```
>
> styles.xml, where I'm using a custom theme (which I think is the key)
>
> ```
>  <style name="GradientLight" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
>     <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
>     <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/progressBar</item>
>     <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/greenButton</item>
>     <item name="android:buttonStyleSmall">@style/greenButton</item>
>     <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/listView</item>
>     <item name="android:itemBackground">@drawable/menu_selector</item>
>     <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/spinner</item>
> </style>
> <style name="listView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView.White">
>  <item name="android:background">@drawable/background</item>
>  <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/list_selector_background_green</item>
> </style>
> ```
>
> From: [Override context menu colors in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604562/override-context-menu-colors-in-android)

Check this post for one more possible solution.

Hope it help